# Why do I need to register an application to upload files to google drive?

Tags: cordova, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a cordova application from which I would like to upload some user data to the user's google drive account.

I was hoping I could do this by:

1. Opening an InAppBrowser and get the user to log onto google and returns an OAUTH token
2. Use the OAUTH token to use the google api to save files to the user's google account

However, the [google drive javascript](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js) page says that I first need to register my application.

**Question**: why do I need to register an application?

**Question**: does google charge me for api calls or limit the number of API calls made by users from my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your perplexity.

Well the data and Google account belong to the user, also your app is used by the user, but the role does the action "store" is your app, not the user itself.

If user log in Google and store something in it, of course no allowance is required.
But if your app does this, you need an allowance from the user.

Sounds like carrying coals to Newcastle?

The consent page includes the name of app and scopes the app request, here scope is important information for users.

For example, if no scopes is involved, that means after a user log in Google account in your app, your app can operate user's data in Google, but operate includes CRUD various data in user’s account, over even send message on behalf of the user. It's dangerous!

So the consent page tells the user who is the app, and what it wants? The user may know who the app is, but about the action scope, the user pays more attention. After all, no one want all apps operate his address book.

Comment: Ah, thanks Owen.  So my application will not get billed for API's used by the user?

Comment: Hi,
Currently, Drive API has a courtesy limit: 10,000,000 requests/day, and it will not charge you.
You can get that information from [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).
Google APIs Console lists all services and their limit and Pricing if they have.

Comment: Thank you - found it. I think this information rules out google drive as a storage option for my application. The application courtesy limit (rather than just user limits) makes me nervous.  If my app got really popular, then I'm at google's mercy asking for more allowance.  Also, google seem to have a tendency to give stuff free for a while and then start billing.  My app will be free to users, so there is no revenue.  It is a shame that the drive API usage was based solely on the user account and not the application.

Comment: I don't support you know any alternatives to drive? - see my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701939/apis-for-remotely-storing-files-for-my-applications-user)

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/console/help/

This link will help you on how and why to register your google apps. And once, you are ready, register your app in https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I still don't get it. The app will just be storing **a user's data** in **the user's google account**. I would have expected the billing and usage allowances to be between google and the user, and not between google and my application?