# APIs for remotely storing files for my application's user?

Tags: cordova

I have a requirement to store files remotely from a cordova/phonegap application.

I have been looking at:

- **Dropbox**
- **Google Drive**

However, these seems to want my application to be registered with them, but I can't see whey this is required (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694778/why-do-i-need-to-register-an-application-to-upload-files-to-google-drive)).

I have also looked at **Amazon S3**.  Howeever, I'm not sure my users will be happy to create an Amazon account just so that their files can be persisted.

**Question**: Are there other service provider API's available that will allow me to create a user account on the service provider and upload/download files?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at various Open Source cloud solutions (example: [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/)). Using provided API you can implement user registration in your app. To have a very basic (OpenStack) installation you really need only 1 server and then you can easily extend your cloud adding additional servers / resources.

Comment: Thanks Wizzard, but I'm looking for a storage service provider so I don't have to spend lots on my own infrastructure.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.